# Get all public methods and attribute getters and pass them to liquid_methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, liquid

If we want to make methods accessible from liquid templates we need to declare them as `liquid_methods` in our model, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  liquid_methods :name, :adress, :any_method_we_want

  ...
```

The thing is our model has a lot of stuff (attributes and public methods) defined and it'd be quite a goal to manage and not to forget declare them as liquid_methods when we add new ones, not to mention a really ugly list on the top of our model. So the question is, I'd like to declare that all attribute getters and public methods should be "liquidized", is there a more fancy way than always declaring them manually for the liquid to be accessible like in the example? How would you do that?

To get the point something like this in pseudo code (probably not working):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  methods = self.public_methods + self.attribute_names

  liquid_methods methods

  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I use Liquid and have the same issue. Here is my counsel against your proposed solution:

The entire purpose of Liquid is to not over expose the data or methods of your app to the random people writing the Liquid templates.

(If you will only have trusted people writing the templates, then don't use Liquid. Instead use erb, haml, dryml or other choices.

And if you have two sets of people (trusted and untrusted) then let your trusted people use one type of template and send the untrusted people to Liquid.)

If you expose your methods by default then it is much much harder to test that you haven't exposed too much.

Sure, you end up with an ugly list of methods which you're exposing to the Liquid templates. But that way, you're positive that ONLY those methods are being exposed.

Instead, just add tests about what should be exposed through liquid. Then you'll be sure that the needed minimum will be exposed to the Liquid templates.

HTH.